# A connection attempt failed error

Tags: php, mysql

Hi everyone I'm trying to set up a MySQL connection to a web server on **Dreamweaver** but keep getting the error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond.

How can I resolve this?

The connection seems to be working fine when I test it on the actual web server but it does not work when I run it off the local web server (off **127.0.0.1**). What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

can you connect to it from the command line?? mysql -u your_user -p -h thehost if you're connecting remotely your mysql user should have a specific GRANT that specifies the ip you are connecting from